# json_encode from PHP to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the problem, that the success: function doesn´t work.
The Update is all fine, and I´m getting an Json, but I´m just getting the error Message:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

I was looking for this, and found always hints about

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

I have this, but it still doesn´t work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

That´s my .js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#benutzerDaten").submit(function(){
    var inhalt = $("#usr_vorname").val();
    if($("#usr_vorname").val() === ""){
      $("#ausgabe").text("das Feld ist leer");
    }else{
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",  
        data: "usr_vorname=" + inhalt,
        //data: inhalt,
        beforeSend: function(x){
          if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
          }
        },
        url: "jsonphp.php",        
        success: function(data){
          if(data.success === true){
            alert("success");
          }else{
            alert("nein");
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
          //alert(ajaxOptions);
        }
      });
    } 
    return false;
  });
});
```

Thats the json.php

```
if(isset($_POST['usr_vorname'])){
  $usr_vorname = $_POST['usr_vorname'];
  $userInstanz->updateUser("usr_vorname", $usr_vorname);
}
```

and that´s the part of my class that makes the $json

```
   $json = array(
      "success" => true,
      "result" => "Benutzer wurde aktualisiert!"
    );
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Firebug shows this:

```
{"success":true,"result":"Benutzer wurde aktualisiert!"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change into:

1.Just replace the $.post instead of $.ajax.

2.No need of beforeSend: function(x){ }

3.json_encode($json); alone enough, No need of header('Content-type: application/json');

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#benutzerDaten").submit(function(){

        var inhalt = $("#usr_vorname").val();

        if($("#usr_vorname").val() === ""){

            $("#ausgabe").text("das Feld ist leer");

        }else{

            $.post("json.php",{ usr_vorname:inhalt}, function( data ){

                if(data['success']== true){

                    alert('success');

                }else{

                    alert('something went wrong');
                }


            },"json");
        }
    });
});
```

**Json file:**

```
  if(isset($_POST['usr_vorname'])){

        $usr_vorname = $_POST['usr_vorname'];

        $userInstanz->updateUser("usr_vorname", $usr_vorname);

      }

        $json = array(
           "success" => true,
          "result" => "Benutzer wurde aktualisiert!"
       );

     echo json_encode($json);
```

Hope It helps....

Comment: Please dont just post code, explain what you did and why. Also, please remove the useless newlines as formatted code reads easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: I´ve found the solution.
I´ve tricked myself with an 
print_r($stmt);
witch I have forgotten to comment out.
Now it´s all perfect.

Thanks.